# Wrap Div to new line when there is no more space

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, html, position

I am working on a web application (asp.net mvc3)

I have a Main div. I want to add lots of div inside that main div.

But I want them to be like this: Divs should appear next to each others on a line, and when there is no more space left, the next div will wrap to a new line.
(Similar to writing a text, when there is no more space on this line the next word will wrap to a new line)

I tried to use `display: inline;` to make the appear next to each others, but how can I make them wrap when they reach the end of the Main div?

Is there a way to do it without hard coding the positions? because divs are added dynamically so i don't know how big will they be or their number

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the `<span>text</span>` tag? It's kinda like a div but inline by default. I know they will appear right after one another (and you can style it with css the same) but I'm not sure what you meant by `how can I make them wrap when they reach the end of the Main div?`

Comment: You can try `float:left`. And BTW, why do you use divs, not spans?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `display: inline-block` - http://jsfiddle.net/7FJRr/1/

**UPDATE** If IE7 is still a concern:

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1; 
    *display: inline;
}
```

Comment: @LukLed who cares about IE7 in mid 2012? :) But if anyone - there is a fix

Comment: Thanks. it worked. Actually I received complained from some people, and they had IE 6 and some of them still use windows millenium O-O.  so there is a big chance someone will be using IE7

Comment: @ZoltanToth if youre the one making a website then YOU care about IE7, what possibble reason could you have for wanting to exclude possibble clients? i bet you dont even think about optimising for people with disabilities and screen readers now do you :P

Comment: @Zoltan there is millions of pounds worth of revenue lost yearly from people who have disabilities but couldnt use the service because people didnt think of them. so youre saying someone wants to give you money and youre saying no because they dont use the browser you want them to use? please never run a business...

Comment: @RhysW You have to read carefully - I said that I DO care about people with disabilities and always try to do my best in terms of accessibility. What I don't care about - people with outdated browsers who don't want to upgrade for their own benefit. And please keep your advices about what I should and should not do to yourself.

Comment: This aged nicely

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to do it with the help of flex.

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

For example:

```css
.flex{
  width: 5rem;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex > div{
  width: 2rem;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

http://jsbin.com/uzoruq/edit#javascript,html,live

I used `float:left` to arrange the content divs

I am not aware of solutions that will wrap a div but this will put the divs inline

**EDIT**

If you are willing to use spans you could do this:

http://jsbin.com/uzoruq/2/edit

I used `display:inline` for the spans.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: flex` then `flex-wrap: wrap` then add `justify-content: space-evenly` to make everything look nice.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution. Variant with *flex-wrap: wrap;* fits, but it's not customizable enough.

In order to be able to adjust the width of the floating elements, I suggest wrapping them in an additional block, which will also have a property flex-basis.

Example CSS:

```
.wrapping-block {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.wrapping-block .item-container {
    flex-basis: 25%; /* four items per row*/
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.wrapping-block .wrapped-item {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px 0; /* to rows do not merge */
}
```

Example HTML:

```
<div class="wrapping-block">
    <div class="item-container">
        <div className="wrapped-item">Uno</div>
        <div className="wrapped-item">Due</div>
        <div className="wrapped-item">Tre</div>
        <div className="wrapped-item">Quattro</div>
        <div className="wrapped-item">Cinque</div>
        <div className="wrapped-item">Sei</div>
        <div className="wrapped-item">Sette</div>
        <div className="wrapped-item">Otto</div>
    </div>
</div>
```